# How to deal with answers to duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Questions which have been (or are in the process of being closed as a duplicate) often get answers posted anyway.  What's the best way to deal with these answers?  The problem with upvotes (even to the answers, let alone to the question) is that it more or less pulls focus away from the preferred original question and its answers.  OTOH, it doesn't make sense to downvote an answer purely because the question is a dupe.

Is it best just to ignore the answers?  Would it be useful to  have some sort of automated migration or removal of answers once the question is closed?

Comment: I've also considered this question at different occasions: It's partially what led me to the notion of "canonical questions". Other than that, ideally an edit on the original question to accommodate the new answer, combined with a merger of the two questions, could be an option. That's a lot of effort though.

Comment: Old [related discussion on mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97076/263383).

Comment: Concerning merging duplicates, see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4853/2451

Comment: This is not an easy problem in the first place and is made much harder if the question in question appears in the Hot Network Questions. I try to protect any question that appears in the HNQ as a matter of course, but that only does so much good.