# Should useful duplicates be obviously linked from their nominal original question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

There has been much discussion in the past on both Physics and other Metas about [How to deal with answers to duplicate questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7726/145491), especially when the duplicate questions or its answers are useful.
It is possible to merge questions, but this [can be challenging](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12849/145491).

Duplicate questions are closed with a banner and link to the original question, but there is usually no indication on the original question that a duplicate exists with possibly useful answers.
Would it be possible and useful to have the option, where appropriate, to place a banner at the top of  original questions pointing out the existence of possibly useful duplicates?
This could be a precursor to eventual merging, but until that happens it keeps all the relevant answers connected with less work.

Or if a banner is not possible, would it be problematic for users to add something like this to the beginning or end of the original question:

> **Note**: ["This question"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319819/145491) has [a duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22897/145491) which may also have useful answers.

One could add a comment instead of editing the question with a note, but visitors are less likely read the comments, especially if there are lots of comments and they have to click on "Show … more comments".

This question was inspired by today's closing of "[What does the angular momentum vector really represent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/738208/145491)" as a duplicate of "[Is direction of angular velocity just a definition or has a physical significance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/583504/145491)". I wondered if it would be useful to make visitors to the original question aware of the highly scored duplicate answers.

A few other examples where the closed duplicate has interesting highly ranked answers are

- [Should zero be followed by units?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286964/145491)
- [Why is boiling water loud, then quiet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28069/145491)
- [Why do I see better under water using swimming goggles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250363/145491)
- [Is the Higgs boson an elementary particle? If so, why does it decay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454292/145491)

Comment: Don’t the duplicates show up in the “Linked” sidebar on both questions?

Comment: @rob A very good point, and that certainly may be sufficient. (I hadn't noticed that Duplicates are always the first items in the Linked sidebar. I wondered how the order was determined.) I guess I was thinking about casual visitors who may not consider checking out the Linked questions without a more obvious prompt, where "casual" probably includes the vast majority of visitors.

Comment: @DavidBailey I do not know how the linked questions are sorted. I will just point out that when using `q/linked/id` as, for example, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/174521), one can choose from various orderings - such as newest, active, score.

Comment: One issue I can see is that I've seen many cases where a question is marked as a duplicate which is itself closed as a duplicate as something else.  How deep do we want to go here?  Do we link to the duplicate or the duplicate's duplicate ?

Comment: sometimes a duplicate post - I have to click to go to the next duplicate a few times, like "this post is duplicate, click here for answers" ->"click here for answers" -> (..) then it arrives at the "duplicate of duplicates" or , what to call it :) (I am not sure what a duplicate message exactly says but, something on those lines) and I agree with @StephenG-HelpUkraine  as well;